# Use moment.js with ts-loader in webpack 4

Tags: typescript, webpack, momentjs, webpack-4

No matter what I try, I can't get moment.js to load inside a TypeScript file when building with webpack4.

```
[tsl] ERROR in /app/Repository/JFFH.Site/Resources/Private/JavaScript/Angular/schedule/schedule.component.ts(18,30)
npm_1    |       TS2694: Namespace '"/app/Repository/JFFH.Site/Resources/Private/node_modules/moment/moment".export=' has no exported member 'Moment'.
```

The TypeScript file that I'm trying to get working:

```
import * as moment from "moment";

interface IEvent {
    title: string;
    startTime: string;
    startTimeObject?: moment.Moment;
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

My Webpack4 rules:

```
        {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/, /Packages/],
            use: {
                loader: 'ts-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [/core-js/, /@babel\/runtime/],
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the `ts-loader`.

As I've found out that it can be omitted since `babel-loader` now understands typescript, it works.